# Multicloud: Authenticate Googe Cloud Translation Client from AWS Lambda (Nodejs)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, federated-identity, google-auth-library, google-cloud-translate

### Problem

I am trying to access a Google Cloud service (Cloud Translate API) from my AWS Lambda using Nodejs and serverless framework.   The system already works perfectly when I use a Google Service Account Key, so that validates that the two cloud services are operational and functional.

However, I'm trying to follow best practice and use Google's Federated Workforce ID instead of a Service Account Key. ([Docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation-with-other-clouds)).

However, I'm getting an error:
`FetchError: request to http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 169.254.169.254:80`

I've followed the directions in the docs several times, including creating the workplace pool and downloading the client config file. And I have the environment variable set to the config file:
`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ./clientLibraryConfig-fq-aws-apis.json`

The Google Auth picks up the credentials file (I can see by running a console.log on const "client"), and it retrieves my projectId in auth.getProjectId();.

But when it comes to initiating the TranslationServiceClient, I get this:

### Error

"errorMessage": "request to http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 169.254.169.254:80",

### Code

```
"use strict";

const { GoogleAuth } = require("google-auth-library");
const { TranslationServiceClient } = require("@google-cloud/translate");

//////////
// This function gets translation from Google
//////////

const getTranslations = async (originalClipArray, translateTo) => {
  // G Translate params
  // const projectId = "rw-frequency";
  const location = "global";

  const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
  });
  
  const client = await auth.getClient();

  const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();


  const translationClient = new TranslationServiceClient()

  console.log("past translationserviceclient constructor");


  // Build the params for the translate request
  const request = {
    parent: `projects/${projectId}/locations/${location}`,
    contents: originalClipArray,
    mimeType: "text/plain", // mime types: text/plain, text/html
    targetLanguageCode: translateTo,
  };

  // Call Google client
  // try {
  const response = await translationClient.translateText(request);
  console.log(`response`);
  console.dir(response);
  return response;
  // } catch (error) {
  //   console.log(`Google translate error raised:`);
  //   console.log(error);
  // }
};

module.exports.getTranslations = getTranslations;
```

Answer (score 0):

The request that gives you a timeout retrieves [security credentials for EC2 instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html).  Apparently, your Lambda is using a GCP library intended for EC2.  Hope this helps!